# How to calculate point coordinates after perspective transform and rotation

Tags: python, opencv

I want to calculate the new coordinates of a point in the image after getPerspectiveTransform and rotation (90 degrees clockwise) are applied.

To briefly describe a problem, the aim is to align the rectangle and set a landscape orientation (width > height).

The original rectangle is determined by four vertices. In some cases, OpenCV switches width and height. In such cases, additional 90 degrees rotation is applied. This, however, sometimes causes the rectangle to be rotated inversely. To correct this, the idea is to compare the y coordinates of the top-left and bottom-left vertices.
for the given list of vertices, a mapping is given, determining the vertices (TL, TR, BR, BL). The idea, therefore, is to apply the same transformation to original vertices - either only warpPerspective or warpPerspective and 90 degrees rotation, and after that, compare y coordinates.

So the question is, how to get the transformation matrix that either only applies warp or rotates as well, to apply such transformation to the points for which the relative location concerning the object of interest is known.

Example:

```
rectangle_area = [[270.2044677734375, 685.4646606445312], [417.27044677734375, 908.5230957031249], 1.0000191926956177]
rectangle = cv2.boxPoints(rectangle_area)
rectangle = np.int0(rectangle)
src_pts = rectangle.astype("float32")

width = int(rectangle_area[1][0])
height = int(rectangle_area[1][1])
rotate_90 = width < height

dst_pts = np.array([[0, height-1],
                    [0, 0],
                    [width-1, 0],
                    [width-1, height-1]], dtype="float32")

dst_pts = np.array([[0, height-1],
                   [0, 0],
                   [width-1, 0],
                   [width-1, height-1]], dtype="float32")

# the perspective transformation matrix
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_pts, dst_pts)

warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (width, height))

if rotate_90:
      warped = cv2.rotate(warped, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
      # TODO: adjust M in order to represent perspective transform + 90 CW rotation
      h, w, _ = warped.shape
      center = (w/2, h/2)
      points_reprojection_matrix = M * cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, 90, 1)
else:
      points_reprojection_matrix = M # this is incorrect

# calculate reprojected points coordinates
points_reprojected = []
for pnt in src_pts:
      pnt_ = [pnt[0], pnt[1], 1]
      pnt_reprojected = np.dot(points_reprojection_matrix, pnt_)
      points_reprojected.append(pnt_reprojected)

# TODO: check if the y coordinate of pnt[0] is higher than pnt[3] - in case it is, rotate the rectangle for 180 degrees
```

Comment: `cv2.perspectiveTransform` works on coordinates.

Comment: known values are the rotation angle and point coordinates before rotation - how to calculate the coordinates after rotation?

Comment: I think you are looking for [cv2.transform](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga393164aa54bb9169ce0a8cc44e08ff22) method. Something like `pnt_reprojected = cv2.transform(src_pts, points_reprojection_matrix)`. Please make sure your code sample is executable. It would be helpful adding sample images (input and output) ,  with known points, so we can verify the solution.